# Difference between ARM binary MUL and Data Manipulation

Tags: binary, arm, bitmask

Okay, so I do know the difference between `mul` and `add`, `sub` etc.

What I'm asking is about the binary (I need to make an ARM emulator for a project).
[image: Subset of ARM opcodes]

If the `I` bit of a data processing instruction is zero, and the `OpCode` is 0b000X, I'm fairly certain you can get an Operand2 with 0b1001 in the middle, which would give the data processing instruction the same format as the `MUL` instruction.

So how can I tell the difference between these instructions when interpreting?

Comment: you can start at these high level charts, note some of which are buggy in arm documents.  then you dig into the individual instructions and you see closer to the truth, and fewer bugs in those pages.  and then you take a tool that makes code that actually works on an actual arm processor (gnu, etc) and disassemble those instructions and compare those to the sometimes buggy documentation.  Yes sometimes gnu tools are buggy too. there are also several versions of arm documents over time that describe the same instructions comparing those also helps to find documentation bugs and work around them

Comment: as answered note that the assembler will sometimes replace the instruction with something else, depends on the assembler (the tool) not the instruction set.   very possible to make an emulator and remember the hardware can tell one instruction from another (for properly made code) so your emulator can as well.  also there are a number of emulators already out there one of which was written by arm and that tool made the post acorn arm what it is today, as the hardware had to match the emulator to be called good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't tell the difference and more often that not those instructions actual do the same thing, like multiply by 1, 2 which is the same as a left shift, etc.

Comment: Huh, that seems like a pretty clever design. Thanks for your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

In the MUL instruction, the 1001 in bits 4-7 are important. In data processing, it will either have the 4th or 7th bit set to zero.